# How to use a function to pass the result to 'queryset'?

Tags: python, django, class, django-queryset

I'm working on a Python/Django project. I have to use the ***YearArchiveView*** base class, so I have this:

```
class ArchiveView(YearArchiveView):

    queryset = ArticlePage.objects.all()
    make_object_list = True
    date_field = 'date'
    template_name='btcmag/pages/archives_list.html'
    allow_future = False
    context_object_name = 'articles'

    def extract_month(self, article):
        'extracts the starting date from an entity'
        return article.date.month

    def extract_year(self, article):
        'extracts the starting date from an entity'
        return article.date.year
```

Instead of having `queryset = ArticlePage.objects.all()`, I would like to have a function returning the correct Queryset. Something like:

`queryset = getQuerySet()`

At the same time I have to pass in some parameters.

I tried defining the function within the class, calling it with `self` and alone, but I get that the `function` or `self` are not defined.

Where do I have to define the function/method?

How can I pass it to `queryset`?

Comment: What do you mean by *no luck*? We need to see how you implemented your method. did you consider a custom manager with extra method?

Comment: Just edited the question. Basically I get that the function or self is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having `queryset` set, in Django views you can overwrite/use the `get_queryset` method:

```
class ArchiveView(YearArchiveView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...magic here...

        return custom_queryset
```

Comment: Actually really easy: it should be within `self` in `get_queryset`. So in the method you find it: `self.request`.